# java: while loop - statement with a semicolon before going into statements between curly braces?

Tags: java, sorting, while-loop, cycle-sort

I was looking at another page here on stackoverflow and came across a working implementation of cycle sort, but I don't understand how a statement with a semicolon can exist before the curly braces in a while loop. I thought that the while loop is supposed to completely terminate and take no further actions once it finds a statement with a semicolon, so how is it that the code within the curly braces is getting executed? At first glance, I would interpret this as "var" gets incremented with each iteration of the while loop - but I know this is not the case because removing it from that spot and putting the "var++" inside of the curly braces causes an infinite loop.

Under exactly which condition is "var" incremented? Either an explanation, or a link that explains similar syntax:

```
while (checkSomeBool) var++;
{
   //other stuff happening in here
}
```

would be appreciated. Thank you. Below is the code taken from [CycleSort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623509/how-to-sort-an-array-using-minimum-number-of-writes)

```
public static final <T extends Comparable<T>> int cycleSort(final T[] array) {
int writes = 0;

// Loop through the array to find cycles to rotate.
for (int cycleStart = 0; cycleStart < array.length - 1; cycleStart++) {
  T item = array[cycleStart];

  // Find where to put the item.
  int pos = cycleStart;
  for (int i = cycleStart + 1; i < array.length; i++)
    if (array[i].compareTo(item) < 0) pos++;

  // If the item is already there, this is not a cycle.
  if (pos == cycleStart) continue;

  // Otherwise, put the item there or right after any duplicates.
  <while (item.equals(array[pos])) pos++;
  {
    final T temp = array[pos];
    array[pos] = item;
    item = temp;
  }
  writes++;

  // Rotate the rest of the cycle.
  while (pos != cycleStart) {
    // Find where to put the item.
    pos = cycleStart;
    for (int i = cycleStart + 1; i < array.length; i++)
      if (array[i].compareTo(item) < 0) pos++;

    // Put the item there or right after any duplicates.
    while (item.equals(array[pos])) pos++;
    {
      final T temp = array[pos];
      array[pos] = item;
      item = temp;
    }
    writes++;
  }
} 
return writes;
```

}

Comment: It is definitely screwy code (though nowhere near the screwiest I've ever seen).

Comment: It may help to read it like this: `while (checkSomeBool) { var++; }

{ // other stuff }`

Comment: I agree with Hot Licks.  I think that the author was trying to be misleading.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I haven't done very much coding, so this was my first time ever seeing the entire "while" on only one line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `while` loop ends with `var++`

```
while (checkSomeBool) var++; // while ends here
```

The code after that is not part of the `while` loop at all.

```
{
   //other stuff happening in here - not part of the while loop
}
```

Comment: +1. so `checkSomeBool` had better involve `var` (as it does in the OP code), otherwise the loop is executed never or endlessly.

Comment: yes, likely so. unless there's another thread modifying the value of the boolean in the condition, still without a wait call, this is likely to cause a little cpu-lock..

Comment: I was overly vague with the condition within parentheses in my OP. Yes, that boolean condition should indeed have 'var' in there somewhere. The actual code that I was working with is:  `while (item.equals(array[pos])) pos++;`

Answer (score 3):

C-like languages allow you to enclose arbitrary code in braces to create a block scope, with or without other syntactic constructs.
The code in the braces is being executed as ordinary code after the loop.

If you take out the `while` line completely, it will still run.

Comment: I didn't realize that curly braces also served this purpose. Thanks.