# How to keep a string input within a loop

Tags: java, string, loops, input

I'm making a program that takes a string from the user and separates it word by word with a delimiter, and it's almost complete. However, after the first full loop, the next input from the user doesn't pass through the last while loop.

Here's the segment of code I'm talking about:

```
do
  { 
     System.out.println ("\nEntered String: " + s1 + "\n");

     while (input.hasNext())
     {
        word++;

        System.out.println ("Word #" + word + ": \t" + input.next()); 
     }   
        System.out.print ("\nEnter 'q' to quit, enter string to continue:  \t");
        s1 = scan.nextLine();

  } while (!s1.equals("q"));
```

I'm thinking that I need another while loop around the word increment and print line and have the continue sequence within the input.hasNext() loop, because that's how I got a similar program using int to work, but I'm not sure how that would work with strings.

Any advice?

EDIT: to clarify, right now the output of my code looks like this:

Enter a sentence: this is a sentence

Entered String: this is a sentence

Word #1:  this

Word #2:  is

Word #3:  a

Word #4:  sentence

Enter 'q' to quit, enter string to continue:      another sentence

Entered String: another sentence

Enter 'q' to quit, enter string to continue:

I need 'another sentence' to print out like 'this is a sentence'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java: while loop - statement with a semicolon before going into statements between curly braces?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12658242/java-while-loop-statement-with-a-semicolon-before-going-into-statements-betwe)

Comment: What is the value of `input`?

Comment: input is for the delimiter, which is for the string s1 that the user enters. It works almost the same way as here: http://javatutorialhq.com/java/util/scanner-class-tutorial/hasnext-string-pattern-method-example/ but I've altered my code so that it allows user input from the scanner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand exactly what's the problem since your code does not compile. But there is no need for another loop. Here is a bit of code that works:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("\nEnter a sentence:");
String s1 = scan.nextLine();

do
{
    System.out.println("\nEntered String: " + s1 + "\n");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(s1);
    int word = 0;
    while (input.hasNext())
    {
        word++;
        System.out.println("Word #" + word + ": \t" + input.next());
    }

    System.out.print("\nEnter 'q' to quit, enter string to continue:  \t");
    s1 = scan.nextLine();

} while(!s1.equals("q"));

scan.close();
```

Comment: That fixed it! I just needed to place the scanner input in the do-while loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if it works. It has the same results with the one you need.

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s1 = scan.nextLine();
    do {
        String input[] = s1.split(" ");
        System.out.println ("\nEntered String: " + s1 + "\n");
        for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
           System.out.println ("Word #" + i+1 + ": \t" + input[i]); 
        }
        System.out.print ("\nEnter 'q' to quit, enter string to continue:  \t");
        s1 = scan.nextLine();
    } while (!s1.equals("q"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```
 while (input.hasNext())
```

I suppose input is a Scanner object, so you should do something like this before using it (but before entering the loop):

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `scanner.next()` in `while` loop, I would recommend doing the following API:

```
 String.split
 Scanner.nextLine
```

Something like this:

```
 while(input.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = input.nextLine();
    String[] words = line.split("delimeter");
    if(words.length < 1 || words[words.length - 1].equals("q")) {
        break;
    }
 }
```