# Sorting a sequence of numbers from within a file without saving them into an array

Tags: c++, mingw

Is it possible to sort a sequence of numbers from within a file without saving them into an array, and, if yes, how?

Comment: just push every element into a set?

Comment: @billz: I think the point was "not read the entire file into a container", rather than "read it into something that is not an array".

Comment: @billz: I guess the real question is: "How can I sort an arbirtrary number of values from a file with constant memory usage"?

Comment: I am unsure what "constant memory usage" refers to (English is not my first language), but the whole idea is to use up as little memory as possible, yes

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is a text file, rather than a binary file. One of the problems with text files (for storing numbers) is that the numbers are likely different sizes.

Yes, assuming all the numbers take up the same space (which means, if it's a text file, you have padded all the numbers to the same length). [Ok, so technically, it would be possible to do anyway, but that would require reading all the intermediate numbers between two points, and then writing them back again, and then you are almost certainly better of just reading the whole file in and storing it back out again].

As to "how" - the method is pretty much the same as for any other sorting algorithm, read two values, if they are out of order, swap them. There are probably algorithms that "reduce the number of reads/swaps", I have not looked into it.

I expect, if your concern is "I don't have enough memory for the entire file", then you could read a couple of large chunks and sort within/between those chunks. Repeat as necessary. Again, there are probably sorting algorithms specifically for this, but I'm unsure which - I tend to use unix `sort` when I need to sort text files.

The first answer on this page has a link for "comparing sorts"
[How to sort an array using minimum number of writes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623509/how-to-sort-an-array-using-minimum-number-of-writes)

Comment: +1; Remark: If the input and the output file differ one can use a simple `O(n^2)` algorithm, where one doesn't have the "write over stuff" problems (just in case OP wants to create a new file).

Comment: I am unsure what you mean by "...and then writing them back again..." , do you mean that I would write them back up into the text file ? I also don't know how to do that with what I have learned...

Comment: Could you post exactly what the file looks like in your original question? [if the file is very large, just a dozen or so lines would be enough].

Comment: I don't have a specific file, just take any file with n numbers (n<=1000) , the numbers having a maximum of 9 digits.

Comment: If the the file contains only 1000 numbers (and we have a reasonably competent computer, something that is a little better than a digital wrist-watch) then sorting it in memory should be the right thing. It would only use up 4KB of memory. That's definitely a lot faster than reading/writing a file up to a million times because most sorting algorithms will at least read all elements n<sup>2</sup> times.

Comment: It doesn't have to be fast, it has to use up as little memory space as possible. I apologize for being such a greenhorn btw, but I still don't understand how am I supposed to sort the numbers without actually saving them within a container...could you write some code to explain?

Comment: You have a container, it just happens to be a file. But if your file isn't formatted so you can calculate using a constant size where each element goes, you're stuff anyway, you have to read the whole file [minus one element or so, but that's hardly the crucial point].